# NSMutableArray going to zero

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following method where I create an `NSMutableArray` and add some values to it:

```
NSMutableArray * pointsForInterpolation = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//Code to add objects to array
```

I then set a property equal to the array by doing the following within the same method I allocated and initialized the array:

```
self.wavePoints = pointsForInterpolation;
```

self.wavePoints is an NSMutableArray property and it is Strong (`@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *wavePoints;`).  I then do the following:

```
-(void) setWavePoints:(NSMutableArray *)wavePoints
{
    _wavePoints = wavePoints;
    NSLog(@"_wavePoints count %lu", [_wavePoints count]);
}
```

My NSLog shows that _wavePoints has a valid count and is not nil.  I go on to execute some other methods that have nothing to do with the array until I reach this last method:

```
- (UIBezierPath*) createPath 
{
    NSLog(@"Wave points count %lu", [_wavePoints count]);
    NSMutableArray* data = [self.wavePoints mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"ARRay count 2 %lu", [data count]);
}
```

Header:

```
@interface OSWaveView ()

    @property(nonatomic,strong)AVAsset *audioAsset;
    @property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *wavePoints;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray * pointsForInterpolation;
    @property(nonatomic,assign)CGFloat minAmpl;
    @property(nonatomic,assign)CGFloat maxAmpl;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) CAShapeLayer* blueWave;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) CAShapeLayer* redWave;

@end
```

These last two NSLog's reveal a count of zero.  Is my initial array (pointsForInterpolation) getting released?

Comment: Why do you need to mutably copy your property? Shouldn't you already have it retained strongly?

Comment: Also, you might want to double check and see what other objects might be calling `-setWavePoints:` and sending in something that might change `self.wavePoints` unexpectedly...

Comment: Sorry the `mutableCopy` was old code that should have been removed.  I'm looking around and I can't find anything that would call self.wavePoints without me knowing.

Comment: It appears that the initial array `pointsForInterpolation` that `self.wavePoints` points to is going to nil.  Why would that be?

Comment: Can you post the code between pointsForInterpolation creation and assignment to self.wavePoints?

Comment: try init your mutable array with array in your initialisation string.

Comment: @Anton do you mean [NSMutableArray array]?

Comment: arrayWithArray or arrayWithCapacity you should do alloc

Comment: @Anton I tried it out.  Still goes to zero.

Comment: Have you tried declaring pointsForInterpolation as a class variable rather that a variable inside a method? Maybe pointsForInterpolation gets released when it goes out of scope at the end of the method.

Comment: @Zhang I tried doing what said by doing the follow: 
`@implementation OSWaveView
{
NSMutableArray * pointsForInterpolation;   
}`

Comment: with your new code, can you override the setter and see if anything else is calling the setter?

Comment: @rvijay007 I set a break point within my setter.  I only hit the break point once, when the array is initially set.  Then I never hit it again.

Comment: Where are you checking the value of self.pointsForInterpolation? Are you sure those methods that use it aren't being executed before you actually instantiate the array?

Comment: @rvijay007 I have NSLog's at the beginning of each method that reads the array count.  This class is a `UIView` subclass and after the array is set `layoutSublayersOfLayer:(CALayer *)layer` is executed right away.  The NSLog I placed within `layoutSublayersOfLayer` reads zero.  So the array is going to zero almost immediately.

Comment: Can you post your header file with your @property declaration for pointsForInterpolation?

Comment: Actually, instead of printing [self.pointsForInterpolation count], can you print just self.pointsForInterpolation? Is the array nil or is the array instantiated, but just has zero elements in it?

Comment: The array has elements in it.  The count shows that.  But once I hit the method  `layoutSublayersOfLayer` the array becomes nil.

Comment: I'm starting to conclude that `layoutSublayersOfLayer` is the problem.  I did a simple test by creating an NSString property and setting it to @"Test".  I NSLog the NSString and it reads the correct value, however, once I hit `layoutSublayersOfLayer` I NSLog the NSString again and it is nil...

Comment: Actually use breakpoint to recognise where it's getting null

Comment: @Anton I don't know where I can place a break point that will show where its going null. `layoutSublayersOfLayer` is setting all variables to nil.  If I allocate and init after `layoutSublayersOfLayer` is executed everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) setWavePoints:(NSMutableArray *)wavePoints {
    _wavePoints = wavePoints;
    NSLog(@"_wavePoints count %lu", [_wavePoints count]); 
}

My NSLog shows that _wavePoints has a valid count and is not nil. I go on to execute some other methods that have nothing to do with the array until I reach this last method:

- (UIBezierPath*) createPath 
{
    NSLog(@"Wave points count %lu", [_wavePoints count]);
    NSMutableArray* data = [self.wavePoints mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"ARRay count 2 %lu", [data count]);
}
```

Your interpretation is slightly off. Your logs would return 0 even if _wavePoints is nil. You should do an explicit check to see if the array is nil.

`NSLog(@"%@", self.wavePoints)` should return something other than nil/zero if it was properly initialized. Once that is confirmed, then you know that the array is not the problem, but rather you are not adding any values to the array, which would point the problem to your for-loop, and not having anything to do with the array being nil'ed out.